# What term describes tribes that lived in a winter home and a summer home?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some indigenous tribes were nomads, moving from place to place, following game.

Some tribes were sedentary, staying in one place to farm.

Others created two places to live, usually one place in the summer and one place in the winter.

What term describes the last group?

Comment: It sounds a bit like the plutocrat tribe.

Comment: I think "migratory" has been used to describe this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Transhumance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transhumance):

"A type of pastoralism or nomadism, a seasonal movement of livestock between fixed summer and winter pastures."

Comment: An excellent word that I had never heard before.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest 'migratory'. I also think that 'nomadic' might be usable. While some definitions insist nomadic means 'wandering' others seem to think it fits the bill.

Comment: Floridians is the common term up here.

Comment: @Elliot - And we call them snowbirds down here.